# Trouble with creating WPF window extended on the title area (like Office 2007/2010)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I want to make WPF window extended on the title area (like Office 2007/2010). I implemented DwmWindow (see [DwmTest.zip](http://cid-7a281cf3ee613966.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Public/DwmTest.zip)) where I put required stuff. Commonly, it works fine except one disgusting thing: the window appears as white rectangle (see [DwmIssue.png](http://tinypic.com/r/244utfb/5)) and after a few second this rectangle disappears and the content of the window is shown (see [DwmIssueCorrect.png](http://tinypic.com/r/25jk0sl/5)).  This bug is essential only for my window. If I remove this lines it works fine (without it aero will not showed on title):

```
HwndSource mainWindowSrc = HwndSource.FromHwnd(handle);
if (mainWindowSrc != null) mainWindowSrc.CompositionTarget.BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent; 
NativeMethods.MARGINS margins = new NativeMethods.MARGINS(0, 50, 0, 0);
NativeMethods.DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(handle, margins);
```

How can I eliminate this white rectangle?

(To run a sample [DwmTest.zip](http://cid-7a281cf3ee613966.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Public/DwmTest.zip) WinVista/7 with DWM enabled and .NET 4.0 is required. To compile sample you will need Visual Studio 2010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no direct solution to your problem, but you might want to have a look at [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2010/05/10/wpf-shell-integration-library.aspx) which I have read yesterday. As far as I understood, it is about a WPF wrapper framework for the needed functionality, so that you can specify all the stuff in XAML. I have not tried it, but it seems to be from guys from Microsoft, so they probably know how to do that...